# ModuleNotFoundError when running coverage run -m pytest . in GitHub Actions

Tags: python, pytest, github-actions, code-coverage

I have a very simple project like below

```
//
├─ src/
│  ├─ sample/
│  │  ├─ __init__.py
│  │  ├─ simple.py
├─ tests/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ test_simple.py
```

When I tried running the coverage command below in the my local laptop, it runs okay and generates `coverage.xml`

```
coverage run -m pytest . && coverage xml
```

But when I run in the GitHub actions using the config below, it returns error

```
    - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: '3.11' 

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pytest coverage

    - name: Run test
      run: |
        coverage run -m pytest .
        coverage xml
```

The error is below

```
Run coverage run -m pytest .
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.6, pytest-7.4.3, pluggy-1.3.0
rootdir: /home/runner/work/openapi-splitter/openapi-splitter
collected 0 items / 1 error

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
____________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_simple.py _____________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/runner/work/openapi-splitter/openapi-splitter/tests/test_simple.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.6/x64/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_simple.py:7: in <module>
    from sample.simple import add_one
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sample'
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR tests/test_simple.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=============================== 1 error in 0.11s ===============================
```

Why did this happen and how to fix this?

Comment: Check you `sys.path` in tests as it seems that you are running your tests locally from different scope than in the GitHub actions. Therefore your import `sample.simple` cannot import you tests as you are probably in `//` instead of `src` (so proper import would be `src.sample.simple` when you add `__init__.py` in `src directory`.

Comment: I had a similar experience it worked when I used `poetry run coverage run -m pytest` in the GitHub action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `test_simple` file, the correct import should be

```
from src.sample.simple import add_one
```

as `src` is *contained* in the directory in which the actions are executed.

EDIT:

If you want `sample` to be the uppermost level of your project, do what famous packages like `numpy` do: name the thing the intended package name, and/or remove `src`:

```
//
├─ sample/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ simple.py
├─ tests/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ test_simple.py
```

where now `sample` is the name of your package. Then your Actions script will work.

Comment: `src` isn't meant to be imported like this. It's a directory that contains the source, but the whole point of using it is to avoid accidental importing.

Comment: That's the programmer's decision. By _far_ the most common choice is to name that folder the name of the package, e.g. `numpy`. As a C++ programmer, my bet is that using `src` is merely a habit brought from more low-level/compiled languages. For OP's problem, another solution may be to simply bring `sample` one level up, completely removing `src`. That'd make the code work with the current pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't installed your code in the GitHub action, and I don't see in your example where you do.  You've installed it locally, now you need to add a step to the action to install it there.